# Android, is it possible to customise permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, customization

Android has lots of permission as default, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

My question is am I able to define my own created permission? If yes how can I define and implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Declaring and Enforcing Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#declaring)

To enforce Permissions there are many functions like `Context.checkCallingPermission()` , `Context.checkPermission()` to check whether the Application has the specified permission.